# Is @strongify and @weakify really safe in iOS?

Tags: ios

I find this kind of usage in ReactiveCocoa and libextobjc. And I know that when @strongify was compiled it has been change to:

`@try {} @finally {}
 __attribute__((objc_ownership(strong))) __typeof__(self) self = self_weak_;`

When the block was executed it will create a local variable named self and replaced the global variable.

```
 @interface A: NSObject
    @property (nonatomic,copy) TestBlock testBlock;
 @end

 @implementation A
 - (void) someAPI{
    @weakify(self)
    self.testBlock = ^{
        @strongify(self)//the global variable of self was captured by this block before this line was executed.
        if (self != nil)
        {
            [self doSomethingAwesome];
            [self doSomethingAwesomeAgain];
        }
    };
 }

@end
```

My questions:
1. Is the local variable was generated before the block was executed.
2. If the block was copied and never been called will it generate retain circle?

Sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@weakify and @strongify are macros. Macros get expanded during preprocessing, before your code is compiled. When you expand the macros it becomes clear that there is no retain cycle here.

```
- (void) someAPI{
    __weak A *self_weak_ = self;
    self.testBlock = ^{
        //suppress shadowing variable warning
        _Pragma("clang diagnostic push")
        _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"")

        __strong A *self = self_weak_; //this is a new reference, the original self is not being captured.

        //pop shadowing variable warning
        _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")

        if (self != nil)
        {
            [self doSomethingAwesome];
            [self doSomethingAwesomeAgain];
        }
    };
 }
```